# IAutomationObject not found when running Flex application

Tags: apache-flex

i get the following error when trying to run a flex application (which has been working fine!). I was playing around with some different setttings trying to optimize the compiled size. I've put these settings back to the defaults as much as I thought but still getting issues.

I remember getting this error before but cant seem to remember how I fixed it - nor any useful information about how to fix it again!

Anybody know?

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class IAutomationObject could not be found.

```
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\3.1.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:299]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_initProgressHandler()[E:\dev\3.1.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2225]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\3.1.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:398]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't encountered this, but here are some suggestions on things I would try:

- Did you exclude any classes in the compiler settings?
- If you're using Flex Builder, try doing a clean (Project > Clean...).
- If that doesn't help, remove all eclipse and flex builder files from your project and create a new project that points to your existing sources.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I had changed an externally referenced .swc file's embed mode set to 'External' as opposed to using it as an 'RSL'.